# Web scraping in R with RCurl and XML - using xpathapply

Tags: xml, web-scraping, rcurl

I am trying to scrape all the result URLs from the following webpage:

```
http://www.attheraces.com/results/25-Jul-2018
```

Basically, I am looking to get a dataframe with the following links in it:

```
http://www.attheraces.com/racecard/Bath/25-July-2018/1400
http://www.attheraces.com/racecard/Bath/25-July-2018/1430
http://www.attheraces.com/racecard/Sandown/25-July-2018/1750
```

etc.
(I think there are 42+ UK and IRE ones).

I have started with the RCurl and XML libraries as follows:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
url = "http://www.attheraces.com/results/25-Jul-2018"
txt = getURL(url)
txt = htmlTreeParse(txt, asText = TRUE, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
```

Within the HTML, i can see that all the urls that i want are in descriptor:

li class="meeting-race"

However, now I am not sure how to use the the xpathApply function in order to extract all the URLs in one go into a dataframe?

Many thanks.